# PHP Syntax Checking with lint and how to do this on a String, not a File

Tags: php, command-line, syntax-error

First off, I'm confused on how to run PHP in the command-line.  I've been reading several articles on the web and they all say that you need a CLI (Command Line Interface).

Basically, I have PHP files, and I want to call something like this:

```
php -l somefile.php
```

But I'm wanting to check a *string*, not a file! How can this be done?  Can using *STDIN*, *STDOUT*, or *STDERR* help with this at all?

If so, how? Can someone provide an example here?

Also, where do I place that above code?  I don't have access to a command-line (I don't think), or do I just place it within a PHP file itself that will run? Will it execute this code, in that case, within the command-line?

I'm completely clueless on how this PHP command-line thing works... Can someone please help shed some light on this exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want lint code (not within a file) the only option is to write a wrapper.

Assuming your $HOME/bin precedes /usr/bin, you could install your wrapper in $HOME/bin/php that has a different option for command-line linting.  The wrapper would create a temporary file, put the code in there, run `/usr/bin/php -l file` and then delete the temporary file.

HTH.

Comment: Do any servers block access to the PHP commandline?  If so, than using this method is pointless.  I am building a software that needs to cater to all or most servers...

Comment: BTW, thanks for your help on this! +1, will wait for more answers if any before I accept this as my answer.

Comment: @SolomonClosson I assume you're asking about hosting providers.  AFAIK most providers run PHP as a CGI since they don't want to bring down the entire Apache server due to a bug in PHP or some core dump.  That is the case if they are running Apache 2.x.  If they are running Apache 1.x any way they are automatically protected but I haven't seen a hosting provider running PHP as an Apache module.  Now, since PHP is available as a CGI the binary might be present so you would have access to run it.

Comment: Ok, is it safe to say that 90% of all hosting providers have a binary that is present?  Meaning that `/bin/php -l file` will work?

Comment: @SolomonClosson if you ask me, yes.  May be you could check a few big ones.

Answer (score 15):

You can check code with `php -l` from STDIN by piping it in. Example:

```
$ echo "<?php echo 'hello world'" | php -l

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 2

Errors parsing -
```

Here the ending semicolon `;` is missing after the single quoted string. If you add it, the error goes away and PHP tells you so:

```
$ echo "<?php echo 'hello world';" | php -l
No syntax errors detected in -
```

The dash `-` in  `Errors parsing -` or `No syntax errors detected in -` stands for STDIN. It's commonly used for that.

Another way is to write the code you want to lint your own (or copy and paste it). This works by using the lint switch with `--`, entering the code and finishing it by entering <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> (Linux) / <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> (Win) on a line of its own:

```
$ php -l --
<?php echo "1"
^Z

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 2

Errors parsing -
```

BTW, the `-r` switch which is normally intended to provide code for executing, doesn't work in this case and it gives an error:

```
$ php -l -r "echo 1"
Either execute direct code, process stdin or use a file.
```

Most likely because it is intended for running code and thats it for, no linting. Also it is without the opening PHP tag.

---

From all these options, the first one makes probably most sense if you want to pipe it in (you could also operate with [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) in case you need more control). Here is a quick example using PHP's `exec`:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Syntax Checking with lint and how to do this on a string, NOT a FILE
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/12152765/367456
 * @author hakre
 */

$code = "<?php echo 'hello world'";

$result = exec(sprintf('echo %s | php -l', escapeshellarg($code)), $output, $exit);

printf("Parsing the code resulted in; %s\n", $result);

echo "The whole output is:\n";

print_r($output);
```

The output is as follows:

```
Parsing the code resulted in; Errors parsing -
The whole output is:
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 1
    [2] => Errors parsing -
)
```

Comment: Good stuff, in me linux but it would be CTRL+D however (end of input), as CTRL-Z would be go to background.

Comment: I guess that depends on the terminal. Using git bash here on windows XP. Or it's probably the windows php binary?

Comment: Nah, it's just the difference between the shells. CTRL+Z in Unix-like == send `SIGTSTP` to process, in Windows == send EOF. Nothing the php binary can do about that.

Comment: That works in most cases, but if your class namespaces happen to start with a character that creates an escaped character when after a backslash, such as \t for a tab from 'namespace foo\test\bar;' then PHP doesn't get the exact code you pass it. Running it through $code = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $code); should fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out [phpstan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan). It is a linter built with PHP, and works a lot like phpunit but for linting code. You can write configs, control linting levels, and include/ignore folders.

It also has proper exit codes.

https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan

If using that isn't possible, I used [this script here](https://gist.github.com/mathiasverraes/3096500#gistcomment-1575416) and it works nicely.