# Codeigniter Chat Application Not submitting form data and also giving displaying an 500 Internal Server Error in javascript console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to implement a chat application using the codeigniter framework but on form submit, the form data does not get submitted and the submit button becomes disabled. when I check on the javascript console, I get an error 500 Internal Server Error for the url localhost/biko/chat/conv/xsapSHKs/msg which should fetch new messages. I am pretty conversant with PHP but am not pretty good with ajax or javascript. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Below is my Controller, model and view.

**Controller (chat.php)**

```
public function conv($slug = FALSE, $action = FALSE) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mid', '', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fid', '', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', '', 'trim|required');
    if ($slug === FALSE) {
        if ($_POST['bcdhgfjhggvgzs'] != '') {
            $this->Chat_model->startConv();
            redirect('/conv/chat/'.$_POST['bcdhgfjhggvgzs'], 'refresh');
        }
    } else {
        if ($action !== '' and $this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
            $this->Chat_model->save($action);
        }
        $data['pageTitle'] = 'Chat';                
        $data['pageKeywords'] = 'chat';
        $data['pageDescription'] = 'Chat with Us';
        $data['converse'] = $this->Chat_model->get_conversations($slug);
        $data['ifempty'] = count($data['converse']);
        $data['content'] = "chat/chatty";
        $this->load->view($this->frontend_template, $data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function save($action) {
    $from = $this->input->post('mid', TRUE);
    $descId = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);
    $to = $this->input->post('fid', TRUE);
    $msg = $this->input->post('text', TRUE);
    $created = mktime();
    
    switch ($action):
    case 'new':
        $descId = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);
        $created = mktime();
        $msg = $this->input->post('text', TRUE);
        $from = $this->input->post('mid', TRUE);
        $to = $this->input->post('fid', TRUE);
        if(empty($msg)){
            $json = array('status' => 0, 'msg'=> 'Enter your message!.');
        }else{
            $data = array (
                'desc_id' => $descId,
                'from' => $from,
                'to' => $to,
                'msg' => $msg,
                'time' => $created,
                'status' => '1'
            );      
            $qur = $this->db->insert('chat_msg', $data);
            $insertId = $this->db->insert_id();
            if($qur){
                $this->db->where('id', $insertId);
                $qurGet = $this->db->get('chat_msg');
                while($row = $qurGet->row_array()){
                    $json = array('status' => 1, 'msg' => $row['msg'], 'lid' => $insertId, 'time' => $row['time']);
                }
            } else {
                $json = array('status' => 0, 'msg'=> 'Unable to process request.');
            }
        }
    break;
    case 'msg':
        $from = $this->input->post('mid', TRUE);
        $to = $this->input->post('fid', TRUE);
        $lid = $this->input->post('lid', TRUE);
        if(empty($from)){

        } else {
            //print_r($_POST);
            $where = array('to' => $to, 'from' => $from, 'status' => '1');
            $this->db->where($where);
            $qur = $this->db->get('chat_msg');
            if($qur->num_rows() > 0){
                $json = array('status' => 1);
            }else{
                $json = array('status' => 0);
            }
        }
    break;
    case 'NewMsg':
        $from = $this->input->post('mid', TRUE);
        $to = $this->input->post('fid', TRUE);
        
        $where = array('to' => $to, 'from' => $from, 'status' => '1');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $qur = $this->db->get('chat_msg');

        while($rw = $qur->row_array()){
            $json = array('status' => 1, 'msg' => '<div>'.$rw['msg'].'</div>', 'lid' => $rw['id'], 'time'=> $rw['time']);
        }
        // update status
        $where = array('to' => $to, 'from' => $from);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $qur = $this->db->update('chat_msg');
    break;
endswitch;
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
return $this->set_output($json);
}
```

**view**

```
    <?php
if ($this->auth_user_id != $converse['from']) { $fid = $this->auth_user_id; } else { $fid = $converse['to']; }
$myid = $this->auth_user_id;
?>
<script src="<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>assets/chat/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>assets/chat/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>assets/chat/livestamp.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>assets/chat/style.css">
<div class="chatcontainer">
      <div class="chat" id="chat">
        <div class="stream" id="cstream">

      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
          <form method="post" id="msenger" action="">
            <textarea name="msg" id="msg-min"></textarea>
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $converse['id'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $myid;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="<?php echo $fid;?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="sb-mt">
          </form>
      </div>
      <div id="dataHelper" last-id=""></div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        if($('#msenger textarea').val().trim() == ""){
            $('#msenger textarea').val('');
        }else{
            $('#msenger textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            $('#sb-mt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   // Disable submit button
            sendMsg();
        }       
    }
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#msg-min').focus();
    $('#msenger').submit(function(e){
        $('#msenger textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $('#sb-mt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   // Disable submit button
        sendMsg();
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});

function sendMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo WEBSITE_URL .''. uri_string() ?>/new',
        data: $('#msenger').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(rsp){
                $('#msenger textarea').removeAttr('readonly');
                $('#sb-mt').removeAttr('disabled'); // Enable submit button
                if(parseInt(rsp.status) == 0){
                    alert(rsp.msg);
                }else if(parseInt(rsp.status) == 1){
                    $('#msenger textarea').val('');
                    $('#msenger textarea').focus();
                    //$design = '<div>'+rsp.msg+'<span class="time-'+rsp.lid+'"></span></div>';
                    $design = '<div class="float-fix">'+
                                    '<div class="m-rply">'+
                                        '<div class="msg-bg">'+
                                            '<div class="">'+
                                            'Me'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                            '<div class="msgA">'+
                                                rsp.msg+
                                                '<div class="">'+
                                                    '<div class="msg-time time-'+rsp.lid+'"></div>'+
                                                    '<div class="myrply-i"></div>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>';
                    $('#cstream').append($design);

                    $('.time-'+rsp.lid).livestamp();
                    $('#dataHelper').attr('last-id', rsp.lid);
                    $('#chat').scrollTop($('#cstream').height());
                }
            }
        });
}
function checkStatus(){
    $fid = '<?php echo $fid; ?>';
    $mid = '<?php echo $myid; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo WEBSITE_URL .''. uri_string() ?>/msg',
        data: {fid: $fid, mid: $mid, lid: $('#dataHelper').attr('last-id')},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(rsp){
                if(parseInt(rsp.status) == 0){
                    return false;
                }else if(parseInt(rsp.status) == 1){
                    getMsg();
                }
            }
        }); 
}

// Check for latest message
setInterval(function(){checkStatus();}, 200);

function getMsg(){
    $fid = '<?php echo $fid; ?>';
    $mid = '<?php echo $myid; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo WEBSITE_URL .''. uri_string() ?>/NewMsg',
        data:  {fid: $fid, mid: $mid},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(rsp){
                if(parseInt(rsp.status) == 0){
                    //alert(rsp.msg);
                }else if(parseInt(rsp.status) == 1){
                    $design = '<div class="float-fix">'+
                                    '<div class="f-rply">'+
                                        '<div class="msg-bg">'+
                                            '<div class="">'+
                                            $fid+
                                            '</div>'+
                                            '<div class="msgA">'+
                                                rsp.msg+
                                                '<div class="">'+
                                                    '<div class="msg-time time-'+rsp.lid+'"></div>'+
                                                    '<div class="myrply-f"></div>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>';
                    $('#cstream').append($design);
                    $('#chat').scrollTop ($('#cstream').height());
                    $('.time-'+rsp.lid).livestamp();
                    $('#dataHelper').attr('last-id', rsp.lid);  
                }
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Javascript Console Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot of the javascript console]

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter CSRF error: "The action you have requested is not allowed."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214612/codeigniter-csrf-error-the-action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed)

Comment: I tried out the solutions offered in that question but none of them worked.

Comment: try with `url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/conv/refresh/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?>",`

Comment: I believe it is not a duplicate post as my config parameters are similar to the ones in the previous question. So I believe it is not the same but related.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the    `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';` in config.php file.

Please try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking in console errors check [Network Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) response for the request

1. Check you loaded **form_validation** library and model in before
2. [PHP Lint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12152793/9268941) controller and model files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).